# Android webview hint text

Tags: android, webview, hint

Is there a way to display a hint text in Android's WebView, such as in EditTexts?  As in, text that displays then gets hidden when you start to type?

Comment: Are you looking to have a hint in some field within the HTML that you are showing in the `WebView`? If not, where are you typing?

Comment: perhaps.  so this has to be done via HTML/Javascript and not a property of the Webview in general?

Comment: yeah in the web view you display some HTML page. so inside the HTML you need to handle view related things

Comment: `WebView` is for rendering Web content. So, I ask again: where are you typing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Somewhere in the HTML area, just a standard text type document. I think I'm ok with the given answer, I'll go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject JavaScript-code which will do the trick, just like

```
//Perform click on button 1
webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+
        "document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1].click();");
```

If there was a field for 'password', you could try the following **untested** code:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+
            +"pass = document.getElementById('password');"+
            +"pass.value('Password...');"+
            +"setOnFocus(pass);"+

            +"function setOnFocus(element) {"+
                +"element.onfocus = function() {"+
                    +"element.value='';"+
                +"}"+
            +"}");
```